Pump.fun Bonding Curve Complete Event
I want to track all pump.fun tokens where the bonding curve has been completed before getting listed on raydium.
Is there a call/event in the account info that I can track such as "initialize2" instruction that indicates when the Raydium pool is seeded? Or should I use the event subscriptions using the PumpFun SDK or is there any better way?

Using PumpFunSDK would be the easiest way to do it. You could use Solana WebSocket API, to detect PumpFun contracts that interact with Raydium Contracts, and then use particular parameters to identify what interaction it is, but its too much manual work.
Event subscriptions would be better to create and handle.
